# asp.net - display data in ascx dynamically from results in c# document

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, dynamic, ascx

I have a cs document that dynamically changes values depending on array size:

```
size =something.length;
if(size==1)
{
something1="a";
}
if(size==2)
{
something2="b";
}
etc....
```

In the ascx file I want to display the results dynamically based on the array size in the CS file.

```
 <asp:Label ID=something1 runat=serve></asp label>
 <asp:Label ID=something2 runat=serve></asp label>
 <asp:Label ID=something3 runat=serve></asp label> ....etc
```

How would I do this?

Comment: Are the labels based on the content in the array or based on your switch (if) that indicates the size of the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
size =something.length;
if(size==1)
{
something1.Text = "a";
}
if(size==2)
{
something2.Text = "b";
}
etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe he wants the labels inside a user control to be updated based on the parent page.  Here is an example of that.

Default Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="WebUser" Src="WebUserControl.ascx" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:WebUser runat="server" ID="ucMyControl" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
ucMyControl.TextToShow = "My Text";
```

User Control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMyText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

User Control Code Behind

```
 private string m_textToShow;

    public string TextToShow
    {
        get
        {
            return m_textToShow;
        }
        set
        {
            m_textToShow = value;
        }
    }


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.txtMyText.Text = m_textToShow;
    }
```

Comment: LowTide: Yes that is basically what I want to do, but if I have 5 items in my array in the  c# file I need 5 items to display in the ascx file. The array value has to be dynamic because the amount always changes.

Comment: Adding labels dynamically in the user control would be the right way to do it.  You could create a public property of type Dictionary and then set that to your list from the parent page.  On the control side, just loop through the dictionary and add labels dynamically, or just use a placeholder control to put in the text you want.